# Is it possible for S3 notifications to SQS to fail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have setup an S3 bucket to publish messages for each PUT and POST actions. Files get uploaded to that bucket using CLI. It does work fine but out of 4 files pushed sequentially, only one triggers a message. I am not sure that this has always happened but it is happening consistently now. Note that it does *not* happen when I upload file manually (i.e. I always get a message per file).

I have made sure that there is no downstream system processing the messages (as a confirmation, I still see the original message triggered after the first file).

Is there any reason to believe that this AWS feature is not reliable? Since this is unlikely, what could be the problem here?

Comment: Did you define your event as `s3:ObjectCreated:*`? Or `s3:ObjectCreated:Put`?  I would speculate that the cli might be using multipart for uploads, so a `Put` notification would not catch these while a `*` notification would.  I have not found any reason to believe notifications to be unreliable.

Comment: Michael, that was exactly the problem. I changed it from Put/Post to * and it now works as expected, thanks! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by Michael in the comment, the problem was that the bucket only listened to `s3:ObjectCreated:Put`. What was happening is that all other files but the first one were uploaded using multipart which was not triggering any message creation.

I modified the bucket to trigger messages on  `s3:ObjectCreated:*` and it now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [RaySF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30113401/379173) answer, I've fixed the issue directly in the AWS console.

1. Sign in AWS console
2. S3
3. Find your bucket and click on it
4. Properties tab
5. Events
6. Edit the related event
7. Change from **PUT** to **All object create events**

[image: S3 event]