# Issues using Lambda and BOTO3 to copies files between buckets

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've been given a task to copy uploaded .zip or .tar objects from Bucket A to Bucket B, but am having issues once the file seems to get above approximately 17 MB, the lambda function appears to not fire off and I am not sure why.  I've tested sized from 1B to 16MB and appears to run just fine, but as soon as the file gets above 17 MB though, it seems to not run or I guess time out. Thoughts on what is happening?

I played around with using copy_object and the managed transfer (commented out), but they both fail at the same size.  Thoughts?

Suggestions?

```
import re
import boto3
import json
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^& *()<>?|}{~:]')
    max_file_size = 30000000000

    for record in event['Records']:
        startTime = record['eventTime']
        source_bucket_name = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        source_object_key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        source_object_size = record['s3']['object']['size']

    copy_source={
        'Bucket': source_bucket_name,
        'Key': source_object_key
    }

    source_object_base_key = os.path.basename(source_object_key)

    if (source_object_size > max_file_size or regex.search(source_object_key)):
        print("Object is " + str(source_object_size))
        print("Object should be moved to failed directory")
        s3_client.copy_object(CopySource=copy_source, Bucket=fail_bucket, Key=source_object_base_key)
        s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Key=source_object_key)
#        s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, fail_bucket, source_object_base_key)
#        s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Key=source_object_key)
        return {
            'statusCode': 422,
            'body': json.dumps('File is either too big or invalid')
        }
    else:

        print("Object is " + str(source_object_size))
        s3_client.copy_object(CopySource=copy_source, Bucket=success_bucket, Key=source_object_base_key)
        s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Key=source_object_key)
#        s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, success_bucket, source_object_base_key)
#        s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Key=source_object_key)
        return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps("File is valid ")
        }
```

Comment: Does it not run, or does it timeout? Those are two completely different issues with two completely different solutions. Check your AWS Lambda logs to determine that.

Comment: I have 5 test objects I am working with at the moment, 1MB, 5 MB, 10 MB, 16 MB, and 17 MB.  When I upload them all to Bucket A, the first four files get copied to Bucket B, and file sizes are printed to cloud watch.  This basically happens within a second of the object being uploaded.

When I upload the 17 MB file, I get nothing in cloud watch.

Comment: This is likely duplicate of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387051/lambda-s3-put-function-not-triggering-for-larger-files

Comment: Wow, thank you that was exactly what was going on.  Appreciate your help and quick turn around, as I was spinning my wheels for the past few hours, as I moved from copy_object, to managed copy, to asking on here.